I have problems with a Dell Latitude 5550, it does not suspend
I just bought a Dell Latitude 5550 and installed Ubuntu version 24.04.1 LTS but the computer keeps turning on. Does anyone know how I can fix this incompatibility problem?

Please edit your question and add more details. Did the installer finish with no errors? What does "the computer keeps turning on" exactly? Any other OS installed? Can you boot the other OS successfully?
